# How do i convert a dictionary with unequal list as value to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a dictionary with an unequal list as values like this

```
dict_data = {
    "Data 1": ["cool", "fantastic"],
    "Data 2": ["spam", "hello", "howdy", "foo"],
    "Data 3": ["good morning"],
}
```

I want something like this as output

```
Data 1     Data 2  Data 3
cool       spam    good morning
fantastic  hello
           howdy
           foo
```

I have tried this which I found on this forum

```
def transpose(cols):
    return map(lambda *row: list(row), *cols)

with open('result.csv','w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file,dialect = 'excel')
    headers = dict_data.keys()
    items = transpose(dict_data.values())
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(items)
```

But it only outputs the first row

```
Data 1     Data 2  Data 3
cool       spam    good morning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the best answer but I always convert the data I want to export as csv to a pandas dataframe. This solution also works well for unequal list values.

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_data["Data 1"])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_data["Data 2"])

master = pd.concat([data1, data2], axis=1) 
master.to_csv("file_name", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Worked well for me.

Comment: Clear case of the right tool for the right job. Time to learn Pandas :)

Comment: Yeah i think so :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your data via the trailing value after `Data` in the key, and then use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
import re, csv, itertools
dict_data = {'Data 2': ['spam', 'hello', 'howdy', 'foo'], 'Data 3': ['good morning'], 'Data 1': ['cool', 'fantastic']}
sorted_result = sorted(dict_data.items(), key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))
with open('filename1.csv', 'w') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows([[a for a, _ in sorted_result]]+list(itertools.zip_longest(*[b for _, b in sorted_result], fillvalue='')))
```

Output:

```
Data 1,Data 2,Data 3
cool,spam,good morning
fantastic,hello,
,howdy,
,foo,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to transpose is a good approach for small data. Where things went wrong for you seems to have been the rows of data being of uneven length. It all works fine if you pad the short rows with empty strings before transposing:

```
import csv

dict_data = {
    "Data 1": ["cool", "fantastic"],
    "Data 2": ["spam", "hello", "howdy", "foo"],
    "Data 3": ["good morning"],
}


def transpose(cols):
    return map(lambda *row: list(row), *cols)


def padright(list_to_be_padded, normalised_length):
    return list_to_be_padded + [''] * (normalised_length - len(list_to_be_padded))


no_of_rows_in_csv = max(len(phrases) for phrases in dict_data.values())
# fieldname is first column (pre-transpose)
# all lists of phrases normalised to same length
output_data = [[fieldname] + padright(phrases, no_of_rows_in_csv)
               for fieldname, phrases in dict_data.items()]
output_data = transpose(output_data)


with open('result.csv','w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file,dialect = 'excel')
    writer.writerows(output_data)
```

Result:

```
Data 2,Data 3,Data 1
spam,good morning,cool
hello,,fantastic
howdy,,
foo,,
```

Note: you might as well handle the field names/column headings (the original dict keys) as part of the transpose rather than deal with them separately.

Final thing: Iterating over Python dictionaries does not return members in a defined order, which is why the `Data 2` column has appeared first in my results. If you want your final data columns in a certain order, then have a look at the Python class `OrderedDict` or, as another answer mentioned, you could sort the data by key before transposing.