# How to create csv file with dictionary key containing string as well dictionary key containing list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

```
name = {} 

name["one"] = "onestring"
name["two"] = "twostring"
name["three"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
name["four"] = ["string", "hello"]

Expected output should be like

one            two           three      four

onestring    twostring        1         string
                              2         hello
                              3
                              4
```

**how to create a csv file with above format? Dictionary values has some normal string values and some has list values. How to create a csv with above format??**

Comment: Do you have an error while creating a CSV? Maybe this can help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Expected output should be like

one            two                  three      four

onestring    twostring        1              string
                                         2              hello
                                         3
                                         4

Comment: I've edited the question please check once again...

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144570/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-with-unequal-list-as-value-to-csv) answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i convert a dictionary with unequal list as value to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144570/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-with-unequal-list-as-value-to-csv)

Comment: no that's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short solution (mostly from here [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths) (duplicate?)):

```
import pandas as pd

name = {}

name["one"] = "onestring"
name["two"] = "twostring"
name["three"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
name["four"] = ["string", "hello"]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k, v in name.items() ]))

df.to_csv("tmp.csv")

print(df)
```

output:

```
         one        two  three    four
0  onestring  twostring      1  string
1        NaN        NaN      2   hello
2        NaN        NaN      3     NaN
3        NaN        NaN      4     NaN
```

Comment: Yes this is working and another thing is we can do this

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(name) and replace the duplicates with null values

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
import csv

name = {'one': 'onestring', 'two': 'twostring', 'three': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'four': ['string', 'hello']}

# Be sure types are str or list only
assert(all(type(x) in (str, list) for x in name.values()))

csv_filename = "names.csv"

# Get length of the biggest list
max_length = 0
for key in name:
    value = name[key]
    if type(value) is list:
        list_length = len(value)
        if list_length > max_length:
            max_length = list_length


# Replace strings and lists by only lists, of equal length
equal_lengths_dict = dict()
for key in name:
    value = name[key]
    if type(value) is str:
        replacement_list = [""] * max_length
        replacement_list[0] = value
        equal_lengths_dict[key] = replacement_list
    elif type(value) is list:
        value_length = len(value)
        if value_length < max_length:
            number_empty_strings_to_add = max_length - value_length
            empty_strings_to_add = [""] * number_empty_strings_to_add
            replacement_list = value + empty_strings_to_add
            equal_lengths_dict[key] = replacement_list
        elif value_length == max_length:
            equal_lengths_dict[key] = value
        else:
            print("error")
    else:
        print("error")


# Get field names (header row of csv)
fieldnames = list(name.keys())

# Get values that will be on the same rows
csv_rows = list()
# Csv header
csv_rows.append(fieldnames)
# Other rows
list_of_values = equal_lengths_dict.values()
for index in range(max_length):
        one_row = list()
        for value in list_of_values:
            one_row.append(value[index])
        csv_rows.append(one_row)


with open(csv_filename, "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerows(csv_rows)
```

You will have to add some checkings and tests.

Perhaps you could rename the title of your question with someting like this : "Writing a dictionary to csv file with key/value pairs representing columns and with values of unequal length (strings and lists of variable lengths)".

Comment: Yes it does, the output of this code is what you wrote as the expected output. Could you provide more information than "No, it's not working " so I could help you ?

Comment: The good thing about continuing on stackoverflow is that it could help others.

Comment: the output of your code is
onetwothreefour
onestringtwostring1string
2hello
3
4

Comment: but i wanted output like i posted in my question...

Comment: Try to read what Pranav Hosangadi said in his comment. And if you want, post an expected output as comma separated csv in order to be clearer.